# Moodle - is password secure when send with a POST request via REST?

Tags: web-services, rest, moodle

I guess that when someone sends data with HTTP POST, it is possible that data to get accessed by someone unauthorized (via a sniffer maybe?).

I want to use REST server in moodle lms.

I have created everything and in my tests I use curl (as stated in Moodle documentation) to POST the data from the client. Now there is no place in the code where the password is encrypted so I guess it is sent unencrypted.

Or am I wrong?

Does Moodle encrypt the password behind the scenes and then hashes it to the db?

Am I missing something about the whole web services concept?

Comment: There is nothing perfectly secure but using https for the call would be a first step (https://www.yourmoodle.com/login/token.php)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to encrypt the data during transmission from your client to the Moodle server use https instead of http. HTTP alone leaves you vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks or sniffers. When calling the Moodle web services, always use https! This applies even to ones where you aren't sending passwords. You want your web service token to remain secure too so always use https. Check out https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Creating_a_web_service_client. From that page: "We highly recommend to do it securely with HTTPS"